# Eclipse Android XML Layout Header and Footer

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

Hi im trying to get a row of buttons at the top of my activity, a row of buttons at the bottom and a webview in between .  The top and bottom row will be anochored and the webview will scroll according to its data .

My code below is not quite working.  Can anyone help me out?.  At the moment The webview is sitting below the two button bars why is this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.appname.app.SegmentedRadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/segment_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@id/button_one"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:minWidth="40dip"
                android:text=" Description "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_two"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:minWidth="40dip"
                android:text=" Images "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_three"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:minWidth="40dip"
                android:text=" Audio "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_four"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:minWidth="40dip"
                android:text=" Weblinks "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
        </com.appname.app.SegmentedRadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main Menu" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scan_exhibit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scan New Exhibit" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer" >
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your `WebView` is in a `RelativeLayout`, you cannot call the `layout_above and layout_below` on it, since the other layouts are not within the same `RelativeLayout`. These options only apply to objects within a `RelativeLayout` in the way you're doing it.

Simply put your `WebView` in between the other layouts, you don't even need a seperate layout for it.

Give this a try:

**Re-editted: Instead of using a `LinearLayout` I put your entire layout in a `RelativeLayout`. Then your option does work. Try this, it seems to work for me but I'm missing your custom classes.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.appname.app.SegmentedRadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/segment_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@id/button_one"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:minWidth="40dip"
                android:text=" Description "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_two"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:minWidth="40dip"
                android:text=" Images "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_three"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:minWidth="40dip"
                android:text=" Audio "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_four"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:minWidth="40dip"
                android:text=" Weblinks "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
        </com.appname.app.SegmentedRadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Main Menu" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scan_exhibit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scan New Exhibit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `LinearLayout`is vertical having three children in the other of ,  and . Try putting the `WebView` between the linear layout code
.

Comment: I cant do that though as the webview is being defined as a relative layout with the following android:layout_below="@id/header" android:layout_above="@id/footer" > so these (header and footer)need to be defined first in my linear layout part